# Gsm switch to turn individual lights on

Tags: led, gsm

looking for some more help. I now have my led consumption sussed but have run into another obstacle which I require some help with.

I have 8 x individual lights which I have decided can be turned on and off via gsm switch. Now I don’t want 8 gsm switches I only want 1 which will be wired into the master light you could say. Now the question I have is when I operate the gsm switch via mobile phone I want all the lights to turn on. Can this be done via Bluetooth or a Wi-Fi relay as all the lights will be within close proximity. Would be great if somebody could detail the correct equipment. It will all be running 12v dc.

Thanks

Comment: It won’t have wifi available it will be used in remote areas. I am trying to pair all the lights so when the master comes on they all turn on.

Comment: So would I need 8 wired in each light. When power is applied to one they will all activate? It could be beyond my capabilities

Comment: You need a wifi relay for each light. I use S26 Sonoff, but there is also other "models". I think can be used also alone with GSM. Show a "picture" of exactly you want.

Comment: Sorry when you say picture I only have the gsm I would like to use. From then on I don’t know what I need. 

The lights are housed in a 120 x 120 x 60 mm electrical project box. 
2x 21700 batteries feeding a boost converter which was going to go to the gsm switch. When text the gsm switch the light will turn on. I would just like the further 7 lights to turn on at the same time. I wasn’t sure if a simple Bluetooth relay was available that when powered would power the next Bluetooth relay.

Comment: Ok. You should update the question with these informations (sending sms ...). I think you need an application on your GSM (receiving SMS and then sending a command through BT or WiFi to boxes). And use also some BT or WFi relays in the boxes.

Comment: Something as this : https://www.hackster.io/makerrelay/esp8266-wifi-5v-1-channel-relay-delay-module-iot-smart-home-e8a437

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would it be possible for you to show me how you would do it with the wiring. 
I would be using this gsm device https://www.locksonline.co.uk/Universal-GSM-Switch-with-Autodialler.html

Comment: Sorry. Don't know this device. Does it seem it does not have WiFi or BT?

Comment: Maybe not. Do you have a idea on how you would make this work with your own equipment of choice?

Comment: A common GSM used as a local Access Point and some boards as above?

Comment: Yes but I don’t know how to make it all work together.

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit complicated. GSM as local Access Point. Search in the parameters ... Connexions ... Access Point mobile and modem ... Then go to the article "hackster.io ..." and set up the board (may be long).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134086/discussion-between-russell-and-antonio51).

Comment: If you want all lights to switch on/off together, you simply connect them all in parallel to the output of the GSM switch.  No need for individual Bluetooth links or other individual controls.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the response. The lights are 8 individual units. So was looking for something that when the output of the gsm switch was live it fed a device that would wirelessly communicate with each light to turn them on.